# Print Prime factor in definite pattern

Tags: java, primes, prime-factoring

I have to print prime factor of any number in this format. Ex: 32 = 2*2*2*2*2
Heres my code. It works fine for all except for 32, it gives:2*2*2*2*2*
How to avoid the last *. 
Heres my code:
     public class PF{

```
public static void pf(int n) {

    for(int i = 2; i< n; i++) {
         while(n%i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i+ "*");
            n = n/i;
         }
    }

    if (n > 2) System.out.print(n); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    pf(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option, you can avoid the * when n=i in your while loop

```
public static void pf(int n) {

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i);
            if (n != i) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            n = n / i;
        }
    }


    if (n > 2)
        System.out.print(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store the values in a list and print them together like this:

```
public static void pf(int n) {

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            l.add(String.valueOf(i));
            n = n / i;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(String.join("*", l));

    if (n > 2) {
        System.out.print("*" + n);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in two ways.

**Type 1**

```
public static void pf(int n) {

    for(int i = 2; i< n; i++) {
        while(n%i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i+ "*");
            n = n/i;
            System.out.print(i>n ? "\b" : "");  //Backspase and remove unwanted character(*) after print
        }
    }

    if (n > 2) System.out.print(n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    pf(n);
}
```

**Type 2**

```
public static void pf(int n) {

    for(int i = 2; i< n; i++) {
        while(n%i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i+ ((i<n) ? "*" : "")); //Skip the unwanted character(*)
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 2) System.out.print(n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    pf(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a formatting problem.  It makes sense to separate it from the initial calculation; better to deal with different problems separately.

You can generate a list of prime factors and write a method to print the list in the correct format.  For this general problem I tend to treat the list as a head with one item that is not preceded by the separator and a tail with all the other entries, each of which is preceded by the separator, your '*' or perhaps a comma in the more common case.  Rather than suppressing the separator after the last entry in the list, think of it as suppressing the separator before the first entry.  It is easier to identify the first element in a list than the last.

My code is not strict Java, but gives you the general idea.

```
void printSeparatedList(factorList) {
  char separator = '*';
  bool firstEntry = true;

  for (int factor : factorList) {
    if (firstEntry) {
      firstEntry = false;
    } else {
      System.out.print(separator);
    }
    System.out.print(factor);
  }
} // End printSeparatedList
```